# Showing a class of objects is $F$-acyclic

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

There's a lemma from homological algebra that I'm using in sheaf cohomology, and I can't remember where else I've seen it. Where are some other key places it is applied?

> **Lemma:** Let $F:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$  is a left exact functor between abelian categories, and let $\mathcal{C}$ have enough
>   injectives. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be a class of objects in $\mathcal{C}$
>   that
>
> 1. Includes all injective objects
> 2. "Completes exact sequences", i.e. if $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is
>      exact and $A$, $B$, are in $\mathscr{S}$, then $C$ is.
> 3. Has $R^1F(X) = 0$ for all $X$ in $\mathscr{S}$.
>
> Then $R^iF(X)=0$ for all $X$ in $\mathscr{S}$ and all $i$.

I included the proof below, if you're interested. I've been using this to show that flabby/soft sheaves are acyclic, but I think I've seen this same cancelling long exact sequence proof before (perhaps with Ext and Tor?). Where?

---

For the proof, we take an object $X$ in $\mathscr{S}$, and a monomorphism from $X$ to an injective object $I$, form its cokernel $C$, and note that by hypothesis 2, the cokernel is in $\mathscr{S}$ as well. So now the long exact sequence of derived functors is 
$$
\require{cancel}
\cancel{R^1F(A)} \to R^1F(I) \to \cancel{R^1F(C)} \to R^2F(A) \to R^2F(I) \to R^2F(C) \to \dotsb
$$
All the injective objects are acyclic, so 
$$
\require{cancel}
\cancel{R^1F(C)} \to R^2F(X) \to \cancel{R^2F(I)} \to R^2F(C) \to R^3F(A) \to \cancel{R^3F(I)} \to \dotsb,
$$
which shows that $R^2F(X)=0$ for all $X$ in $\mathscr{S}$, and now we can bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that's a lemma due to Grothendieck (who else?) from his Tohoku paper: See Lemma 3.3.1 in http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/gk.pdf (english translation). It's used very often, so it's not surprising that you have seen it before - though I can't tell you where :)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't super clear in my question. I'm really looking for salient applications of the theorem, not "where did I read it". :-)